# Angular interface object properties are undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, object, interface

I have following interface for an object -

```
export interface IProduct {
    vendor?: string;
    price?: number,
    quantity?: number,
    savings?: number,
    productId?: number,
    vendorsPrice?: number[],
    title?: string,
    images?: object[]
    ............
}
```

In my component, I get following `this.product` information from API. I have to assign some this object properties to another object (`storedProductInformation`) -

```
let currentProduct = this.product;
console.log('this.product', currentProduct);
let storedProductInformation = {
    Title: currentProduct.title,
    Product_id: currentProduct.productId,
    image: currentProduct.images[0].thumbnail,
    Price: currentProduct.vendorPrice,
    vendorsPrice: currentProduct.vendorsPrice,
    savings: currentProduct.savings,
    vendor: currentProduct.vendor
};
console.log('storedProductInformation', storedProductInformation);
```

I am wondering when I log data with `console.log('this.product', currentProduct)` get all information but when log `console.log('storedProductInformation', storedProductInformation)` sometimes I get `vendorsPrice` and `savings` properties are `undefined`.

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you reset currentProduct.vendorsPrice and currentProduct.savings somewhere else in the program?

Comment: No, I don't reset them anywhere.

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot of the console.log's ?

Comment: Okay, then the code you have provided is not enough to understand as there nothing seems here which is resetting the data. Also, please check by printing this.product after console.log('storedProductInformation',storedProductInformation); and see is it still priting the all details?

Comment: can you post full component body ..?

Comment: Thank you guys for your response, I have to check API data again as they come from multiple source but I can't use `forkJoin` for that. If issue still exists I'll create a `stackblitz` here.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is a case-sensitive language. Please check how do you set "this.product" property.

```
 this.product.Vendor
 this.product.vendor
```

Check if vendor is wrote with capital letter.

Regards